# CDS build command with '@sap/cds' version 3.x doesn't place 'csn.json' in SRV module

Tags: hana, sap-web-ide

I've refactored my project to use the new Cloud Platform Application Programming Model.

My project structure looks file this:

```
<my_project_name>
  - hdb (db module)
  - srv (service module)
  - ui (ui module)
  - cdsrc.json
  - package.json
  - mta.yaml
```

cdsrc.json:

```
{
  "build": {
    "target": ".",
    "tasks": [
      {"src":"hdb","for":"hana","options":{"model":["hdb","srv"]}},
      {"src":"srv","for":"node-cf","options":{"model":["hdb","srv"]}}
    ]
  }
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "<my_project_name>",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "^8.9"
  },
  "files": [
    "hdb",
    "srv"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@sap/cds": "^3.7.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "hdb": "^0.17.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sqlite3": "^4.0.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cds run",
    "build": "cds build/all --clean",
    "deploy": "cds deploy"
  },
  "cds": {
    "requires": {
      "db": {
        "kind": "sqlite",
        "model": [
          "hdb",
          "srv"
        ],
        "credentials": {
          "database": "sqlite.db"
        }
      }
    },
    "folders": {
      "db": "hdb",
      "srv": "srv"
    }
  }
}
```

srv/package.json:

```
{
    "name": "srv",
    "dependencies": {
        "@sap/cds": "^3.7.1",
        "@sap/xssec": "^2.1.12",
        <other_packages>
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node server.js"
    },
    "cds": {
        "requires": {
            "db": {
                "kind": "hana",
                "model": "gen/csn.json"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

srv/server.js:

```
const cds = require("@sap/cds");
const express = require("express");
//other imports
var app = express();

//other middleware

cds.connect();

cds.serve("gen/csn.json", {
        crashOnError: false
    })
    .in(app)
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });

app.listen(port,  () => {
    console.info(`App listening on port: ${port}`);
});
```

When I build my project in WebIDE, it builds all .cds files successfully, and writes the output like this to console:

```
> <my_project_name>@1.0.0 build /hana/shared/HXE/xs/controller_data/executionagent/executionroot/269f9533-c450-4f35-ab0e-b62990473bb5/app/META-INF/.sap_java_buildpack/tomcat/temp/builder/sap.cds.mta/builds/build-838087488308692914/<my_project_name>
> cds build/all --clean

[cds] - cds [3.10.0], compiler [1.13.4], home [/hana/shared/HXE/xs/controller_data/executionagent/executionroot/269f9533-c450-4f35-ab0e-b62990473bb5/app/META-INF/.sap_java_buildpack/tomcat/temp/builder/sap.cds.mta/builds/build-838087488308692914/<my_project_name>/node_modules/@sap/cds]

[cds] - building project [/hana/shared/HXE/xs/controller_data/executionagent/executionroot/269f9533-c450-4f35-ab0e-b62990473bb5/app/META-INF/.sap_java_buildpack/tomcat/temp/builder/sap.cds.mta/builds/build-838087488308692914/<my_project_name>], clean [true]

[cds] - building module [hdb] using [Hana DB Module Builder]
[cds] - model: hdb/<file1>.cds, hdb/<file2>.cds, <all_other_cds_files>

[cds] - building module [srv] using [Node CF Module Builder]
[cds] - model: model: hdb/<file1>.cds, hdb/<file2>.cds, <all_other_cds_files>

12:03:53 PM (DIBuild) 
[cds] - done > wrote output to:
  hdb/src/gen/.hdinamespace
  hdb/src/gen/csv/<file1>_<entity1>.hdbcds
  hdb/src/gen/csv/<file1>_<entity2>.hdbcds
  hdb/src/gen/csv/<file2>_<entity1>.hdbcds
  ...
  srv/gen/csn.json
  srv/gen/_i18n/i18n.json

[cds] - time: 2600.051ms

CDS return code: 0
```

Even though "cds build" command generates those files in "hdb/src/gen" and "srv/gen" folders (I saw all files by SSH-ing to the matchine where SAP Hana is installed, on path from the output above: /hana/shared/HXE/xs/controller_data/executionagent/executionroot/269f9533-c450-4f35-ab0e-b62990473bb5/app/META-INF/.sap_java_buildpack/tomcat/temp/builder/sap.cds.mta/builds/build-838087488308692914/), they are not displayed in Project explorer of WebIDE.

When i build my db module (hdb), it deploys artifacts to HDI container without any error, and I can browse the container with Database Explorer

But running the "srv" module gives me this error:

```
{ Error: Couldn't find a CDS model at: gen/csn.json
    at notFound (/hana/shared/HXE/xs/controller_data/executionagent/executionroot/2dff31be-8521-4d87-a173-f71c65f6b69c/app/node_modules/@sap/cds/lib/models/load.js:59:39)
    at EventEmitter.load (/hana/shared/HXE/xs/controller_data/executionagent/executionroot/2dff31be-8521-4d87-a173-f71c65f6b69c/app/node_modules/@sap/cds/lib/models/load.js:10:50)
    at _loadModel (/hana/shared/HXE/xs/controller_data/executionagent/executionroot/2dff31be-8521-4d87-a173-f71c65f6b69c/app/node_modules/@sap/cds/lib/runtime/serve.js:78:35)
    at <anonymous>
    at runMicrotasksCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:5)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:696:11)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:225:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:646:3 code: 'MODEL_NOT_FOUND', model: 'gen/csn.json' }
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! serve@ start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the serve@ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.


npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /hana/shared/HXE/xs/controller_data/executionagent/executionroot/2dff31be-8521-4d87-a173-f71c65f6b69c/app/.npm/_logs/2019-06-17T11_49_21_417Z-debug.log
```

Sure, path where "cds build" generates csn.json, and path where serve.js wants to load that model are different. But, doesn't it copy all files automatically to the "srv" module execution root?

My current workflow:

- Make changes to CDS files locally with VS Code
- Build project, so it generates csn.json
- Commit changes and push to Git repo
- Pull changes in WebIDE
- CDS Build, so I can deploy changes to database
- Before running "srv" module, copy content from csn.json generated locally, paste it in WebIDE' csn.json, and replace the paths with the one given in CDS build console output.

I appreciate any help to solve this problem.
:)